# Split randomly two lists in python in the same way

Tags: python, numpy

I have two lists that contains numpy arrays with the same size. The list `list_A` has 1000 items where each numpy array has size `20x20x3` and `list_B` numpy arrays of size `20x8`. I want to split both lists randomly in the same way in 100 sub-lists (and in the end each sub_list for `list_A` to contain 100 numpy array and the same for `list_B`). I wrote the code of how to do so just for one list:

```
def partition (list_in, n):
    random.shuffle(list_in)
    return [list_in[i::n] for i in range(n)]

total_lists_A = partition (list_A, 10)
```

However, I want to do the same for `list_A` and `list_B` in the same way and return `total_lists_A` and `total_lists_B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap a `numpy.random.seed` in your function, so as to make it reproducible. Something like (based on your approach):

```
# note: will not work properly if your two lists are different shapes:
def my_partition(list_in, n):
    np.random.seed(1)
    idx = np.random.shuffle(list_in)
    return [list_in[i::n] for i in range(n)]
```

Or (slightly different approach, that should work)

```
def my_partition(list_in, n):
    np.random.seed(1)
    idx = np.random.choice(range(len(list_in)), len(list_in))
    split = np.split(idx, n)
    return [list_in[i] for i in split]
```

Comment: Is it easy to do the same if the second list is just a numpy array with size 1000x20x8?

Comment: I *believe* that my second approach should do, as long as the first dimensions are the same in both arrays (1000)

Comment: It seems that it does not work when the size of the lists cannot be divided with 10. Could be that it is for example 1003.

Comment: In that case I am receiving the error: 'array split does not result in an equal division'

Comment: What would you have it do in case it's not equally divisible by n? If it's to get your subarrays to near-equal size (and equal if possible), replace `np.split` with [`np.array_split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy.array_split)

Comment: Yes I want the soft constraint for equality. Or to add the module to the last sub-list. And by the way the first solution works for the lists even when the size is not equally divisale with 10.

Comment: What about if I use your first method twice for two lists or one list and one numpy array, is it going to split them in the same way?

Comment: I believe the `shuffle` way will not, because the list and the numpy arrays have different shapes

Comment: It seems to work, I do not know if it is correct though. When I input the numpy array it returns a list with contains 10 of 100X20X8 while for list_A is it 10 of 100X20x20x3.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that even with the random seed, the shuffling will be different between the two because of the different shapes of the original arrays. Random seeds only make the same reproducible result if the same input is given. So in the `random.choice` method to create the indices, the input will be the same because both lists have a `len` of 1000, so the input is 1000 in both cases, and passed to `random.choice`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're doing this for machine learning. Look into [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

If you're looking to do this from scratch, you can first generate a vector of length data (`np.arange`), then permute it and use that as your indices (splitting the permuted indices into a train and test set)